# Noise cancellation for known sources

Tags: noise, adaptive-filters

Creating a noise cancelling earphones that cancel/suppress speech is a huge challenge , maybe even impossible.

But what happens if we change the goals a bit:

1. We need to cancel the noise(music,speech) coming from a tv in the same room.
2. We can receive what audio the tv will create , some time before it's created through the speaker.

Does it make it possible to create great noise cancellation ? how would it work ?

Comment: Is the rate at which the headphones can be moved or rotated constrained?  Even 15 cm of movement can reverse the phase at 1 kHz (ouch!)

Comment: @hotpaw2 What kind of method/setup you are talking about ? Please elaborate.

Comment: @hotpaw , true , movement could be an issue.This mean we'll need indoor localization, right ?

Comment: @blacken How are you planning to execute this(I mean the setup). I am unable to understand the issue with movement, can you please elaborate.

Comment: Currently it's just theoretic. So i assume i have maximum powers - i can reprogram the TV any way i wish, put any wireless comm in  the tv as i wish, etc.

Comment: And on the headphones - i'm not limited by hardware - i can use a super gpu, i can add external indoor localization , whatever. I just want to know if theoretically it's possible to achieve much better results from current noise cancellation(which generally sucks) , by having connection to the tv.

Answer (score 2):

If you have audio that will be played by TV beforehand, then this problem becomes almost similar to echo cancellation, i.e. adaptive filters could be used and cancellation will be great.

What we have is the audio that will be played through TV, this audio will be used as reference for adaptive filter and input to the adaptive filter would be the capture(noisy music in earphone/headphone).
so adaptive filter will try to estimate the TV's audio in the earphone capture, then this estimate could be subtracted from earphone capture to get noise free(TV noise) music in earphone/headphone.